# .eq(-1) on a jquery object does not return anything

Tags: jquery

I do not get anything in return when passing `-1` to `.eq()` on a jQuery object. This, from the firebug console, shows my problem.

```
>>> test
jQuery(div#462601759.belt, div#43773862.belt, div#1973215028.belt, div#1811434128.belt, div#486504966.belt, div#100019133.belt, div#1928403755.belt, div#313171064.belt, div#1705880802.belt, div#1964159344.belt, div#1813766347.belt, div#91768319.belt, div#454873181.belt, div#477172806.belt, div#34963942.belt, div#1920955753.belt)
>>> test.eq(-1)
jQuery()
>>> test.eq(-2)
jQuery(div#34963942.belt)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might try updating your jQuery library. I just tested it in firebug on the jQuery site, and it works there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a jQuery 1.4 feature (see [release notes](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14), [docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq/))

Comment: Thank you! The problem was an out of date, compared to the documentation, jQuery copy.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [eq()](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/eq), if you pass in an out of range value (e.g. -1) you will get back an empty jQuery object.

Or are you looking for the [:eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/eq#index) selector?

On a related note, HTML id's [should not start with a digit (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) (there's also IE bugs that crop up if you try).  You should prefix them with an alpha value.